# how to position div in the right side of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I have a small navbar which is split into 2 sections: left section and right section.
The left section contain an arrow icon and the right section should contain 2 icons: envelope & exclamation triangle. I am tried to position the right section on the right corner of the navbar(which is a div). so far no success, I am adding the code below:

```css
.arrow {
     color: gray;
     font: bold 11px "Helvetica";
     padding: 2px;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .arrow:after {
     background: gray;
     color: #FFF;
     content: ">";
     display: inline-block;
     font: bold 11px "Georgia";
     height: 25px;
     line-height: 25px;
     margin-left: 2px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 25px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .upper_menu{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        background-color: #F2F6F7;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
    }

    #upper_right_menu{
        position: absolute;
        float:right;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i class="exclamation-triangle fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="email"><i class="envelope fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you tried the `push` and `pull` helper classes in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the absolute positioning style element from the id #upper_right_menu

```css
.arrow {
     color: gray;
     font: bold 11px "Helvetica";
     padding: 2px;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .arrow:after {
     background: gray;
     color: #FFF;
     content: ">";
     display: inline-block;
     font: bold 11px "Georgia";
     height: 25px;
     line-height: 25px;
     margin-left: 2px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 25px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .upper_menu{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        background-color: #F2F6F7;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
    }

    #upper_right_menu{
        float:right;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i class="exclamation-triangle fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="email"><i class="envelope fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and just remove the `position:relative;` from your navbar `.upper_menu`

See this live demo

```css
.arrow {
  color: gray;
  font: bold 11px "Helvetica";
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
nav{
}
.arrow:after {
  background: gray;
  color: #FFF;
  content: ">";
  display: inline-block;
  font: bold 11px "Georgia";
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.upper_menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #F2F6F7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

#upper_right_menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
      <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
      <a href="#" class="warning"><i class="exclamation-triangle fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="email"><i class="envelope fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify:

```
#upper_right_menu{
    position: absolute;
    float:right;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

to

```
#upper_right_menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
#upper_right_menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to sue `display:table;` solution

```css
.arrow {
     color: gray;
     font: bold 11px "Helvetica";
     padding: 2px;
     text-decoration: none;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .arrow:after {
     background: gray;
     color: #FFF;
     content: ">";
     display: inline-block;
     font: bold 11px "Georgia";
     height: 25px;
     line-height: 25px;
     margin-left: 2px;
     text-align: center;
     width: 25px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .upper_menu{
        position:relative;
        display:table;
        background-color: #F2F6F7;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
    }

    #upper_right_menu{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="upper_menu">
    <div id="upper_left_menu">
        <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="upper_right_menu">
        <a href="#" class="warning"><i class="exclamation-triangle fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="email"><i class="envelope fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```